# Mongoose - Increment a value inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having hard time figuring out how to increment a value in an object within an array

For instance I have this document based on `Poll` schema:

```
{
  "_id": "584b2cc6817758118e9557d8",
  "title": "Number of Skittles",
  "description": "Test1",
  "date": "Dec 9, 2016",
  "__v": 0,
  "labelOptions": [
    {
      "Bob": 112
    },
    {
      "Billy": 32
    },
    {
      "Joe": 45
    }
  ]
}
```

Using express, I am able to get this far:

```
app.put('/polls/:id', function(req, res){
  let id = req.params.id;
  let labelOption = req.query.labelOption;
  Poll.findOneAndUpdate(
    {'_id' :  id},
    {$inc: {`labelOptions.$.${labelOption}`: 1 }},
    function(err){
      console.log(err)
    })
```

where `labelOption` is the one that I would like to increment its value

To be more concise, I am having trouble transversing inside the document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to directly increment the value in the `.find` query if `labelOptions` is an Array of Object. To make it easier, you should change the `labelOptions` type from Array of Objects to Object:

```
"labelOptions": {
    "Bob": 112,
    "Billy": 32,
    "Joe": 45
};
```

Also consider using `.findByIdAndUpdate` instead of `.findOneAndUpdate` if you are querying by the document's `_id`. And then, you can achieve what you want by:

```
Poll.findByIdAndUpdate(
    id,
    {$inc: {`labelOptions.${labelOption}`: 1 }},
    function(err, document) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

UPDATE: If you are persistent on using Array of Objects for `labelOptions`, there is a workaround:

```
Poll.findById(
    id,
    function (err, _poll) {

        /** Temporarily store labelOptions in a new variable because we cannot directly modify the document */
        let _updatedLabelOptions = _poll.labelOptions;

        /** We need to iterate over the labelOptions array to check where Bob is */
        _updatedLabelOptions.forEach(function (_label) {

            /** Iterate over key,value of the current object */
           for (let _name in _label) {

               /** Make sure that the object really has a property _name */
               if (_label.hasOwnProperty(_name)) {

                   /** If name matches the person we want to increment, update it's value */
                   if (_name === labelOption) ++_label._name;
               }
           }
        });

        /** Update the documents labelOptions property with the temporary one we've created */
        _poll.update({labelOptions: _updatedLabelOptions}, function (err) {

            console.log(err);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

There is another way to do this which allows a more flexible document model. If you add a field to your object like:

```
{
  "_id": "584b2cc6817758118e9557d8",
  "title": "Number of Skittles",
  "description": "Test1",
  "date": "Dec 9, 2016",
  "__v": 0,
  "labelOptions": [
    {
      "name": "Bob",
      "number": 112
    },
    {
      "name": "Billy",
      "number": 32
    },
    {
      "name": "Joe"
      "number": 45
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you can do:

```
app.put('/polls/:id', function(req, res){
  let id = req.params.id;
  let labelOption = req.query.labelOption;
  Poll.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
     '_id' :  id,
     'labelOptions.name': labelOption
    },
    {$inc: {
      "labelOptions.$.number": 1 
    }},
    function(err){
      console.log(err)
    })
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

People solved it but, if you use that for if element in array doesnt exits, a solution:

```js
            app.put('/polls/:id', async function (req, res) {
                let id = req.params.id;
                let labelOption = req.query.labelOption;
                const exits = await Poll.exists({ _id: id, "labelOptions.name": labelOption });

                if (exits)
                    await Poll.updateOne(
                        { _id: id, "labelOptions.name": labelOption },
                        {
                            $inc: {
                                "labelOptions.$.number": 1
                            }
                        }
                    );
                else
                    await Poll.updateOne({ _id: id }, {
                        $push: {
                            labelOptions: {
                                name: labelOption,
                                number: 1
                            }
                        }
                    });

            });
```