# Mongoose Nodejs - update array of object with increment value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, arrayobject

im very new with nodejs. Currently, im doing a increment a value into an array object. I have an error after write this code. I want to increment the value of `linkview`. i found something similar with my problem [Mongoose - Increment a value inside an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41072542/mongoose-increment-a-value-inside-an-array-of-objects) but i still cannot solve it. Please help

So this is `User` schema

```
{        
  "_id": "67324b2cc6817758118e9557d8",
  "name": "James",
  "__v": 0,
  "affiliatelink": [
    {
      "storeId": 60014d6e7286763490c3543,
      "storeName": white choc,
      "linkview": 1
    }
  ]
}`
```

and this is my code and the error is `MongoError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query`

```
Admin.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: adminId }, {$inc: {"affiliatelink.$.linkview": 1}}, function(err, result) {
        console.log("ni error "+err)
        //if (err) return next(err)
    });
```

Comment: if you want to increment number in all object's `linkview` then try `{ "affiliatelink.$[].linkview": 1 }`

Comment: As said @turivishal , using the all positional operator `$[]` should works. Check the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#up._S_[]) and also an example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BFP3XrnawGr)

Comment: make sure you have converted `adminId` to object id if you are using mongoose try `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(adminId)`

Comment: thanks a lot @turivishal. Its working now :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which object to update in the array of objects `affiliateLink`

You can use the below query and give it a try:

```
Admin.findOneAndUpdate(
   {
     _id: adminId, 
     "affiliateLink.storeId": "60014d6e7286763490c3543"
   },
   {
     $inc: {
          "affiliateLink.$.linkView": 1
     }
   }, 
   function(err, result) {
        console.log("ni error "+err)
        //if (err) return next(err)
});
```